# Get Music Image

Tags: android

Is there any way to get music Image like what built in android media player do .

for example ,open a music , if music has image, media player shows it is image as background .

where can I find that image ?

Answer (score 0):

This is found in the MetaData of the file itself. You should be able to find it pretty easily if you know how to navigate the database content.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Answer (score 0):

In [mp3 Id3 tags](http://www.richardfarrar.com/what-are-id3-tags-in-mp3-files/). Example [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-retrieve-ID3-art-Image-from-an-mp3-file/td-p/352664).